# Salesforce Oauth Error. 1814 : An unexpected error has occured during authentication

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am creating a meteor app which has login through salesforce using oauth. The login happens through a community app. For the oauth credentials I created a connected app on salesforce(sandbox) with full access.
Initially the login was working fine but then after a few days I started getting the following error.

```
We can't authorize you because of an OAuth error.

1814 : An unexpected error has occured during authentication. Please try again
```

But after this when I attempt the login again (i.e. going back to app screen from the salesforce error screen)from my app, I receive the access code from salesforce and I am able to fetch data through salesforce apis.

We had a requirement of prompting the user to enter username and password each time user logs in. Prompting user to enter credentials every time fixed it for us. What would fix it without having to prompt the user every time?

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to this error: https://support.veeva.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003857954-Error-OAuth-Error-You-didn-t-complete-the-approval-process-before-it-expired-Please-try-again

Basically the session id of the url expired.

If you leave the login screen idle for 10 mins it will show this error.
You might have bookmarked the oauth url instead of the correct

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: I am with @Adriaan , but in order to avoid confusion: The impression of a question asked is very small. It is however still better to phrase "If your problem is ... " and so on, instead of "maybe .... you might have ....". Identifying a possible problem, describing how to find out and providing a solution for that case is a contribution proibably appreciated by those who technically understand the problem (not me, sorry).